# How to know the browser URL from an iframed page, server-side?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, browser, request

I have a child page (e.g. http://www.domain.com/childpage.aspx) within a parent page (e.g. http://www.domain.com/parentpage.aspx) using an iframe.

I'd like to know what the URL of the parent page is using server-side code. would that be possible?

`Request.Browser` gives the URL of the child page only.

I also checked `Request.UrlReferrer` which contains the parent page URL only the first time the page loads. As soon as I click on a link inside the child page, the `Request.UrlReferrer` won't be the parent page any more, it will be the previous page.

I'd like to know what the URL of the parent page is using server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find this out server side, to all intents and purposes it is as if the requests came from separate web pages.

Your only hope would be to get the URL using client script send the URL to the server using ajax.  Bare in mind this will only work if the pages are on the same domain though.  If not you will run into single point of origin restriction issues.